# Knockoutjs mapping and unstructured data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

How to use unstructured data with knockoutjs mapping plugin? 
For example source json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Store #1",
        "address": "City #1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Store #2"
    }
]
```

Store #2 without address.
My template:

```
<ul data-bind='foreach: data'>
    <li data-bind='with: id'>
        <a href data-bind='text: name, click: function () { $parent.view($data, $index()) }'>           
        </a>
        <span data-bind='text: address'></span> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

My viewModel

```
Module.store = function () {

    var self = this;

    self.data = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
    self.init = function () {
        $.getJSON('json/stores.json', function (stores) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(stores, self.data);
        });
    };
};
```

If I run this code, I get error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function
>   (){return address }" Message: address is not defined

For Store #2

How can I set null or empty string for Store #2 address property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view shows the address, then your viewmodel must contain that property.

Make a viewmodel for the individual stores:

```
Module.Store = function (data) {
    this.id = null;
    this.name = null;
    this.address = null;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}
```

and a use mapping definition (see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing-object-construction-using-create)) in your store list:

```
Module.StoreList = function () {
    var self = this,
        mappingDefinition = {
            create: function (options) {
                return new Module.Store(options.data);
            }
        };

    self.stores = ko.observableArray();

    self.viewStore = function (store) {
        // ...
    };
    self.init = function () {
        $.getJSON('json/stores.json', function (stores) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(stores, mappingDefinition, self.stores);
        });
    };
};
```

Modified view (as a general rule, try to avoid inline functions in the view definition):

```html
<ul data-bind='foreach: stores'>
    <li>
        <a href data-bind='text: name, click: $parent.viewStore'></a>
        <span data-bind='text: address'></span> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `create: function (options) {` what `options` and `options.data`  exactly refer to . i am trying to understand mapping is there any link with more detail explanation . knockout docs aren't helpful enough

Comment: You must read more thoroughly. This is straight from [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing-object-construction-using-create): *"The `options` argument supplied to your create callback is a JavaScript object containing: `data`: The JavaScript object containing the data for this child and `parent`: The parent object or array to which this child belongs"*

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seems to me that `knockout-mapping-plugin` has that functionality out of the box. Probably you should consider to try another workaround for that issue, I can see at least two:

1) returning json with `null` from server

2) displaying that span conditionally like:

```
<ul data-bind='foreach: data'>
    <li data-bind='with: id'>
        <a href data-bind='text: name, click: function () { $parent.view($data, $index()) }'>           
        </a>
        <!-- ko if: address -->
        <span data-bind='text: address'></span> 
        <!-- /ko -->
   </li>
</ul>
```